# How do you make a program for a website? What type of skills/code should I know?

Tags: html, css, web-services, amazon-web-services, web

I'm trying to make a mortgage calculator for my website. I want to create it myself and not use another person's code. I want to create a form where someone can fill in the following fields:

1. Sales price of home (In Dollars)
2. Percentage down (%)
3. Length of Mortgage (In Years)
4. Annual Interest Rate (%)

This will then do computations it needs to do to give them all the information they need.

I would like the form to give the visitor details like this example I made:

Mortgage Payment Information

Down Payment:   $15,000.00

Amount Financed:    $135,000.00

Monthly Payment:    $898.16 (Principal & Interest ONLY)
    Since you are putting LESS than 20% down, you will need to pay PMI (Private Mortgage Insurance), which tends to be about $55 per month for every $100,000 financed (until you have paid off 20% of your loan).
This could add $74.25 to your monthly payment.

Monthly Payment:    $972.41 (Principal & Interest, and PMI)

Residential (or Property) Taxes are a little harder to figure out... the average residential tax rate seems to be around $14 per year for every $1,000 of your property's assessed value. Let's say that your property's assessed value is 85% of what you actually paid for it - $127,500.00. This would mean that your yearly residential taxes will be around $1,785.00.
This could add $148.75 to your monthly payment.

TOTAL Monthly Payment:  $1,121.16 (including PMI and Residential Tax)

------------ END OF OUTPUT ---------

I have knowledge using C++, HTML, and CSS. What resources or skills should I have to execute this type of project. I also have a Amazon Web Service (AWS) account.

Any information provided will greatly help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

definitely javascript will be required, use something like jquery as it will simplify DOM manipulation and let you focus on the calculation code.Also maybe you will need to get latest tax and other rates which keep changing, for this you will need a back-end..i will suggest php for this as it will be enough for your purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that if you're attempting to output, and take a lot of user input you should consider **Javascript**, which is useful for taking the input of a user.

As for when you are calculating percentages etc, I would say you should look into **PHP** as that is a language that is useful when calculating numbers and variables together.